# Basic Windows Form using Access Database, DB Items Text Not Displaying In Listbox

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am working with a simple dataset from an Access Database and learning how to get it to connect with C# using Visual Studio and display the data items onto a listbox on my form. The connection is successful and it seems like the items are getting read in because once I click the button that loads the data in, within the listbox I can see the highlighted sections as if there is invisible text there and I can scroll through it but cannot see any text? Any advice would be appreciated.
[What I am seeing on my form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5ini.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;    //Data Access Library for MS Access

namespace DbAccessApp
{
    public partial class FormMember : Form
    {
        //Class Level Objects
        private OleDbConnection dbConn;     //Connection Object
        private OleDbCommand dbCmd;         //Command Object
        private OleDbDataReader dbReader;   //Reader Object
        private Member aMember;             //One of Our Members
        private string sConnection;         //Connection String
        private string sql;                 //SQL Command

        public FormMember()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sConnection =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +  //Connection Provider
                    "Data Source=Data\\MemberDB.accdb";      //Database Source
                dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
                dbConn.Open();

                sql = "SELECT * FROM memberTable " +
                    "ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC;";

                //Create our command object
                dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;

                //Tell the command object which connection to use
                dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

                //Create our Reader Object
                dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();   //Instantiates reader and loads with data

                while (dbReader.Read())//Run as long as I can read from my reader
                {
                    aMember = new Member(
                        dbReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                        dbReader["LastName"].ToString());
                    lstBxMembers.Items.Add(aMember);
                }//end of while

                lblMessage.Text = "Members Loaded";
                dbReader.Close();   //Close reader
                dbConn.Close();     //Close connection
            }//end of try
            catch (System.Exception exc)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = exc.Message;
            }//end of catch

        }//end of btn_click

    }//end of class
}//end of main
```

**Here is my Member class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DbAccessApp
{
    class Member
    {
        #region -- Class Fields
        private string id;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string phoneNumber;
        #endregion -- Class Fields

        #region -- Public Properties
        public string Id { get => id; }
        public string FirstName { get => firstName; }
        public string LastName { get => lastName; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get => phoneNumber; }
        #endregion -- Public Properties

        #region -- Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Default No Arg
        /// </summary>
        public Member()
        {

        }

        public Member(string fName, string lName)
        {

        }
        #endregion Constructors

        #region -- Methods
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
        #endregion -- Methods
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Member` class look like? You need to override the `.ToString` or you can set the listbox `DisplayMember` property.

Comment: By the way, you should be creating a new `Member` object for each iteration through the `while` loop, not use the same object reference over-and-over. Something like `var newMember = new Member(...);` and then `listBxMembers.Items.Add(newMember);`.

Comment: @RonBeyer I added the Member Class code just now.

Comment: @RonBeyer the issue was within my Member Class, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!